# "Segmentation fault" when attempting to play a video from any player

Tags: xubuntu, gpu-driver

After reboot, videos are playing just fine. But later on, when attempting to play any video, I get "Segmentation fault" in any video player (mpv, vlc, parole, ...). After reboot it works again, for a while...

- Xubuntu 16.04.03
- NVIDIA driver, version 384.130